# Express server not responding

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a weird problem, where my server just stopped responding. Also `nodemon` is restarting all the time unless I do `nodemon app.js`.

It worked before, and I don't really know what I messed up.

`app.js`

```
const createError = require('http-errors');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

const {db,} = require('./config/db');

const app = express();

mongoose.connect(db, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
}).then(() => console.log('connected'))
  .catch((e) => console.log(e));

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false,}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './views')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  next(createError(404));
});

app.use((err, req, res) => {
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

I tried to just `GET` a `localhost:3000`. 3000 is the correct port. I also tried 8080 and others. No luck.

I added console.logs all throughout the file and they all fired. I added console.logs to the users and index routers and they both are loaded.

Any ideas?

Edit.

`bin/www` file

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('server:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort('3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

`routes/index.js`

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();
const path = require('path');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

module.exports = router;
```

`routes/users.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const passwordValidator = require('password-validator');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const UserSchema = require('../models/user');

const router = express.Router();
router.get('/', (req, res) => res.text(1));
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  const {email, password, passwordRepeat,} = req.body;
  const errors = [];

  // eslint-disable-next-line
  if (!/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email)) {
    errors.push('Email is invalid');
  }
  const isUserRegistered = await mongoose.findOne({email,});
  if (isUserRegistered) {
    res.json({errors: ['User is already registered',], ok: false,});
  }
  if (password !== passwordRepeat) {
    errors.push('Passwords do not match');
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
  const schema = new passwordValidator()
    .is().min(8)
    .has().digits()
    .has().lowercase()
    .has().uppercase()
    .has().symbols();

  if (!schema.validate(password)) {
    errors.push('Password is invalid');
  }
  if (errors.length > 0) {
    res.json({errors, ok: false,});
  } else {
    const UserModel = mongoose.Model('User', UserSchema);
    UserModel.create({email, password: bcrypt(password, 12),});
    res.json({ok: true,});
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: nmap is a command line tool that can tell you which ports are open.  you could try that before and after launching your app.  don't you need to app.listen() - I haven't leveraged express in years... but seem to remember that as a thing.

Comment: which port is your app listening? share code

Comment: @mehta-rohan As I said. 3000. It's created with Express so there are a lot of files. I'll add the `www` file

Comment: @akaphenom `app.listen()` is used somewhere else with Express.js

Comment: Where is `app.use((err, req, res) ` come from? the order of arguments! does `createError` make this??

Comment: @Saeed.Ataee This just comes by default when you create the app using `express nameOfApp`

Comment: I run your server without your routes (indexRouter and userRouter) and everything works correctly. somewhere in your routers you missed to send response! Are you requesting to `/` ?? If so, provide your indexRouter

Comment: @Saeed.Ataee I added both

Comment: @Saeed.Ataee and yes. The server starts and runs. But using Postman with GET `localhost:3000/` or just going there in the browser doesn't work

Comment: I add these routers and everything still working. Did you check `network` tab in browser? Isn't there any error??

Comment: Does it work though if you send requests? Does it respond with anything? Network tab is empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212414/discussion-between-saeed-ataee-and-alex-ironside).

Comment: After which change, your server just stopped responding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line of code to your `app.js` file:

```
app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: I ended up leaving the `bin/www` code as it was and just added `app.listen(3000)` in the main `app.js` file. Please rephrase the answer and I'll select. We discussed it in the chat, but I must not have been clear about that

Comment: I changed the answer, But still I am thinking Your `www/bin` file has problems. @AlexIronside